# Why am I getting segmentation (core dump)?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, coredump

I did an exercise on youtube and I ended up with the same solution he had but his code was able to get the address of what the pointer is pointing to but when I compiled mine and run it I get an error segmentation fault (core dump), am I somehow accessing memory that I am not supposed to access? How is it that his code was able to run but mine doesn't?
I know the problem lies with printf("The address of num is %d\n", *ptr); but did the line work on youtube but on my compiler it doesn't.

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int print_int_ptr();

 int main(){
   int num;

   num = 10;
   print_int_ptr(num);


   return(0);
 }
 /* dont forget that in between the assignment of ptr = &num */

 /* Take the address of an integer as a parameter, and print out both the
  * address and the integer itself
  */
  void print_int_ptr(int *ptr){

    printf("The address of num is %d\n", *ptr);
    printf("The value of num is %d\n", ptr);
  }
```

Comment: Compile the program with the warnings switched on to identify this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `main()`, `num` is an integer. You passes it to `print_int_ptr(int *ptr)`.

`int *ptr` significates that the first argument for `print_int_ptr()` is a pointer, because `int *` declares a pointer. So as soon as you enter `print_int_ptr()`, ptr is considered as a pointer. But `num = 10`, so any reference to `ptr` will point out address 10, which, obviously, isn't right.

That's exactly what you're doing with `printf("The address of num is %d\n", *ptr);`. `*ptr` dereferences the pointer, it tries to access the value at address 10. But you can't access a value at an arbitrary address, unless you're lucky and the OS gave exactly this one to the process.

Comment: thank you for explaining this, makes so much sense now. XD thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You declared num as an integer and you put it as a parameter in  print_int_ptr function. I think when you declared the print_int_ptr function you declared it wrongly. It should be an int not a ptr?

And if you are not returning any value you should declare the print_int_ptr function as void not int.

Comment: yeah, but I dont see how the parameter of print_int_ptr is wrong? the question that I was trying to solve said, create a function called print_int_ptr that takes one parameter, a pointer to an integer and print out both the integer and its address.

Comment: okay then after your num=10; statement try changing the next line to print_int_ptr(&num); to pass the address of num into the function so that it can be assigned to the ptr u declared in the print_int_ptr function below

Comment: because now u are putting in the integer you want as the parameter and assigning it to be the addresss of ur ptr

Answer (score 0):

Your function is using a pointer `int *`.

So replace the call with `print_int_ptr(&num);`.

And replace the line `printf("The value of num is %d\n", ptr);` with `printf("The value of num is %d\n", *ptr);`.

Also, if you want to print the address, ie value of the pointer, in the `printf` replace `%d` with `%p`.